# Repa: ZipWith'ing over Columns

Tags: haskell, repa

I am wondering if there is a faster/better way to the write the following repa function

```
zipOverColumns ::  (Source r1 a, Source r2 b) 
               => (a -> b -> c) 
               -> Array r1 DIM1 a 
               -> Array r2 DIM2 b 
               -> Array D DIM2 c
zipOverColumns f x y = traverse y id lookup where
    lookup get sh@(Z :. _ :. r) = f (x ! (Z :. r)) $ get sh
```

Here is some sample output

```
>>> toList $ zipOverColumns (*) (fromListUnboxed (Z :. 3)      [1,2,3]) 
                                (fromListUnboxed (Z :. 2 :. 3) [4,5,6,7,8,9])
[4.0,10.0,18.0,7.0,16.0,27.0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Repa 3 context, your implementation is performance-optimal. You could find the following version a bit more readable:

```
zipOverColumns2
    :: (Source r1 a, Source r2 b)
    => (a -> b -> c)
    -> Array r1 DIM1 a
    -> Array r2 DIM2 b
    -> Array D DIM2 c
zipOverColumns2 f col arr = zipWith f ccol arr
  where
    ccol = fromFunction (extent arr) (\(Z :. _ :. r) -> col ! (Z :. r))
```

`zipOverColumns2` is also 15% faster than the original, but it's just a coincidence.

With `yarr` the function looks like:

```
zipOverColumns
    :: (USource r1 l1 Dim1 a,
        USource r2 l2 Dim2 b, DefaultIFusion r2 l2 fr fl Dim2,
        USource fr fl Dim2 c)
    => (a -> b -> c)
    -> UArray r1 l1 Dim1 a
    -> UArray r2 l2 Dim2 b
    -> UArray fr fl Dim2 c
zipOverColumns f col arr = imapM mapF arr
  where
    mapF (r, _) b = do
        a <- col `index` r
        return $ f a b
```

This version is from 30 to 85 % faster, depending on column size (I have tested 4, 8 and 1000). [Gist](https://gist.github.com/leventov/5231268) for playing with it.

Comment: This is the first I have heard about yarr. Looks interesting. What about the design allows it to beat repa here?

Comment: @Jonathan Fischoff Briefly: 1) `repa` iterates over linear index and perform expensive integral division on each iteration to obtain composite index, (row, column). `yarr` keeps indices separately. 2) loop unrolling. Read [the blogpost](http://habrahabr.ru/post/170571/) for more (in Russian, translate the page in Chrome).

Comment: However, Repa 4 will have stream fusion and loop unrolling too, so it will be on par with Yarr for this task.

Comment: when is Repa 4 expected to be released?

Comment: I don't know, ask Ben Lippmeier yourself.